# Variable not changing cross class unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My script needs to change a variable in a different class. I have all of the class references set up and the variable is public yet it still won't change.

This is the sending class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generator : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject rocks;
public int score;
public int HsR;
Player Script;
GameObject player;
float Difficulty;
Rock rock;
Vector2 Easyvel;
Vector2 Mediumvel;
Vector2 Hardvel;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Difficulty = 1.5f;
    InvokeRepeating("CreateObstacle", 1f, Difficulty);
    score = -2;
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    Script = player.GetComponent<Player>();
    HsR = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighscoreReset");
    rock = rocks.GetComponent<Rock>();
    Easyvel = new Vector2(-4, 0);
    Mediumvel = new Vector2(-8,0);
    Hardvel = new Vector2(-12, 0);
}

void CreateObstacle()
{
    Instantiate(rocks);
    score++;
    if (score > 0)
    {
        Script.Score();
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.color = Color.black;
    GUILayout.Label(" Score: " + score.ToString());
    GUILayout.Label(" Highscore: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore").ToString());
    GUILayout.Label("Highscore Reset: " + HsR);
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(300, 10, 50, 30), "Reset"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", 0);
        HsR++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighscoreReset", HsR);
    }

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 10, 50, 30), "Easy"))
    {
        Difficulty = 1.5f;
        rock.velocitypublic = Easyvel;
    }

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 40, 50, 30), "Medium"))
    {
        Difficulty = 1f;
        rock.velocitypublic = Mediumvel;
    }

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 70, 50, 30), "Hard"))
    {
        Difficulty = 0.5f;
        rock.velocitypublic = Hardvel;
        Debug.Log("Hard " + rock.velocitypublic + Difficulty);
    }
}

void Update()
{

}

}
```

The receiving class is here:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rock : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public Vector2 velocitypublic;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        velocitypublic = new Vector2(-4, 0);
        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Random.Range(-2f, 2f), transform.position.z);

    }

    void Update()
    {
        rb2d.velocity = velocitypublic;
        Debug.Log(velocitypublic);
    }
}
```

The variable that needs to be changed is `velocitypublic`. it should be (-12, 0) after I click the hard button yet it is still (-4, 0).

Comment: Bear in mind that `rock` points to a *single* Rock object, not to all of the Rock objects. If you want to change the speed for all of your rocks together, you could either (a) get references to all of them, or (b) use a static variable.

Comment: Im not exactly sure you are actually grabbing the instantiated object and using it. Im not exactly sure your `rock` has any way of knowing which rock it is attached to. I think you want something like `Rock rock = Instantiate(rocks).getComponent<Rock>()` so you actually have hooks into the actual rock you are trying to modify.

Comment: The `OnGUI` is intended only to be used with making controls for the Unity Editor. From the [unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html) *"The IMGUI system is not generally intended to be used for normal in-game user interfaces that players might use and interact with. For that you should use Unity’s main GameObject-based [UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html), which offers a GameObject-based approach for editing and positioning UI elements, and has far better tools to work with the visual design and layout of the UI."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the velocity of all the already spawned instances of the Rock class, and maybe even of the future instances.

In order to change the velocity to ALL instances (present AND future) of the Rock class, you can use the observer pattern with delegate+event, and change how the new Rock instances are spawned.

I'll show you only the needed code.

**Rock Class**

```
using UnityEngine;    

public class Rock : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public Vector2 velocitypublic;

    void Start() {
        Generator.rockDelegate += ChangeVelocity;
        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Random.Range(-2f, 2f), transform.position.z);
    }

    void ChangeVelocity(Vector2 vel){
        velocitypublic = vel;
    }
}
```

**Generator Class** (I've cut all the non-relative code to the solution, just add it yourself)

```
using UnityEngine;

public delegate void RockDelegate(Vector2 vel);

public class Generator : MonoBehaviour {

    public static event RockDelegate rockDelegate;

    public GameObject rocks;
    Vector2 Actualvel, Easyvel, Mediumvel, Hardvel;
    float Difficulty = 1.5f;

    void Start(){
        InvokeRepeating("CreateObstacle", 1f, Difficulty);
        Easyvel = new Vector2(-4, 0);
        Mediumvel = new Vector2(-8,0);
        Hardvel = new Vector2(-12, 0);
        Actualvel = Mediumvel; //<- Here you assign the starting velocity before any Button is pressed
    }

    void CreateObstacle() {
        GameObject rock = Instantiate(rocks) as GameObject;
        rock.GetComponent<Rock>().velocitypublic = Actualvel;
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 10, 50, 30), "Easy")) {
            Difficulty = 1.5f;
            rockDelegate(Actualvel = Easyvel);
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 40, 50, 30), "Medium")) {
            Difficulty = 1f;
            rockDelegate(Actualvel = Mediumvel);
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 70, 50, 30), "Hard")) {
            Difficulty = 0.5f;
            rockDelegate(Actualvel = Hardvel);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the delegate/event combo will change the velocity on all existing instances, whereas the CreateObstacle method will create the new ones with the last selected velocity (Actualvel).

**Edit**: I'll elaborate further on some things.

1) You need of course to have a Rock prefab in the Assets with the Rock.cs script attached to it.

2) If you want to change the velocity of only the already instanced Rock objects, just get rid of Actualvel, i.e. remove the

```
rock.GetComponent<Rock>().velocitypublic = Actualvel;
```

line inside CreateObstacle() and remove the `Actuavel =` inside the `rockDelegate()` of the `OnGUI()`.

3) If you want to change the velocity of only the newly instanced Rock objects, change the

```
rockDelegate(Actualvel = Easyvel);
```

line to just `Actuavel = Easyvel`, and remove the

```
Generator.rockDelegate += ChangeVelocity;
```

line from the Rock.cs script. You can get rid ofc of all the delegate/event lines too.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help!

Comment: `public static event RockDelegate rockDelegate;` generates errors for me

Comment: If you don't say what errors you get, we can't find where's the problem.

Comment: the errors were about it not being a defined namespace and something about a constructor but i have just given up.    the errors were with the RockDelegate bit.

Comment: You need to add `using UnityEngine;` at the start of each script ofc

Comment: boi do you not think i would have noticed if there wasnt a using unityengine at the begining???